# Hash, salt and save password in Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, express, passwords

I have required the Crypto module in Node's standard library. 
I have this POST route which handle a registration form:

```
app.post('/superadmin/add-account', function(req, res) {

  // Shorthand variable
  var doc = req.body;

  crypto.randomBytes(32, function(err, buf) {

    if (err) throw err;

    // Sanitise and transform user input
    ... 

    // Validate user input
    ... 

    var errors = validator.getErrors();

    // Generate new object data
    doc.salt = buf; 
    doc.pass = doc.salt + 'justForNow';

    console.log(doc);
```

When i output the doc (req.body) now i get some values that seems strange to me...
The buf outputted in the console is mostly made up of charachter that resemble a box with a question mark inside. Is this correct? But when i save the buf to doc.salt and output this i get something completly else... "Slowbuffer ae be C5 A3 E3.... and so on"

**Q1:** Do I have to do something special (parse it to something?) with the salt generated by crypto.randomBytes() before i use it concatenation with a string or save it?

**Q2:** The crypto.randomBytes() function exist in async and sync version. Im using the async version but i really dont know why? =P I thought async callbaks was mostly used when handling I/O operations that might take time... Or am I using a callback version of this function because it is actually a complicated process that might take some time and lock the system for som MS if I use the sync version?

**Q3:** I'm not there yet, but I will continue this code with using The Crypto module's hash function for hashing the salt + password and save it to DB. I know i have to create a var like this:

```
var sha256 = crypto.createHash('sha256');
```

But i dont understand how i now use this.

Comment: Ok, i just tried to use the `toString()` on the buf. This seems to give me a more user friendly variable... But if the `crypto.randomBytes()` does not generate a string? What kind of data-type does it generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are generating random bytes with `crypto.randomBytes()`, there isn't anything special to parse the bytes, because they are random. A random byte is composed of two hexadecimal digits, so if you're using `buffer.toString()`, the byte can map to any of the UTF-8 digits between `00` and `FF`.

When using the `randomBytes()` function, you get a `SlowBuffer`, which is an internal class of `Buffer`.

```
<SlowBuffer 76 46 14 02>
// v F \u0014 \u0002
```

If the UTF-8 representation of the two hexadecimal digits don't exist, you get a garbled string:

```
<Buffer 96>
// ï¿½
<SlowBuffer 9e 94>
// ï¿½ï¿½
```

For your second question, it's up to you whether you want to use the asynchronous of synchronous version of the `randomBytes()` function. The amount of CPU time the function uses is also dependent on how many random bytes you ask for. If you wanted a trillion random bytes, you would block the event loop for a sizable amount of time, but if you wanted ten random bytes, that would take only a few milliseconds.

For the most part, if you're putting the operation in a HTTP handler, you should use the asynchronous version, because you want to avoid blocking the event loop at all costs. This is an example of what not to do:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  crypto.randomBytes(1000000000);
});
```

By doing the above, you will stop the server from processing any other incoming HTTP requests.

As for your last question, you have created the hash object, but haven't updated its data or calculated its digest. Use `hash.update()` and `hash.digest()` respectively for the string representation of the hash:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data).digest('hex');
```

The `hash.update()` function accepts two arguments, a chunk of data, and an encoding, while `hash.digest()` accepts an encoding.